# Trigger change option based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to trigger HTML page through AJAX from select option. On load, trigger change have to happen based on "countryCode" value detected from IP address.

For example, if SG detects. Compare "countryCode" and option "ID". Trigger select when both are same.

My present code detects country correctly. But, trigger option not working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selector list">
    <select name="country" id="country">
        <option id="EN" value="global.html">Global</option>
        <option id="AU" value="australia.html">Australia</option>
        <option id="ID" value="indonesia.html">Indonesia</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function getCountryCode () {
   var now = new Date().getTime();
   var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
   var uniqueNumber = now + 'a' + randomNumber;

   $.getScript("/web-services/getCountryCode.js?" + uniqueNumber, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
       if (originCountry){
           var countryCode = originCountry;
           //var countryVal = 'EN';
           // $('.selector #country option[id='+countryVal+']').attr('selected', 'selected');

           $('#country option[id='+countryCode+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
           $('.selector #country').trigger('change'); 
       }
   });
}
```

**HTML generated code: (through inspect element)**

It generate like this and no "id" value for option. How to add id attribute here. we are using http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ plugin.

```
<select name="country" id="country" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
  <option value="HK.html" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: $(' #country').trigger('change');

Comment: sorry.. what is not happening... where is the change handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.selector #country').get(0).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using selectize, you need to use its api to select the value

```js
var cmap = {}; //create a shared object storing the code-value mapping
$('#country option').each(function() {
  cmap[this.id] = this.value;
})
$('#country').selectize({});


//then later in the ajax callback
var countryCode = 'AU';
var $country = $('#country');
console.log(cmap[countryCode])
$country.prop('selectize').setValue(cmap[countryCode]);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/css/selectize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

<div class="selector list">
  <select name="country" id="country">
    <option id="EN" value="global.html">Global</option>
    <option id="AU" value="australia.html">Australia</option>
    <option id="ID" value="indonesia.html">Indonesia</option>
  </select>
</div>
```